# Masking a string without leaving two sequential undiscovered letters (if possible)

Tags: java

I'm building a masker class for a trivia game purpose. My question is, how can I elegantly change my masking method (see below) to make it mask my string in a way that it will never leave two discovered letters, one after the other.

For example, my masker can possibly turn `Michael Jackson` into `**ch*** *******`. I want to eliminate such cases.

My code:

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * This class represents a string masker class.
 */
public class Masker{


    public static String mask(String string, int maskingRatio, String maskingChar){
        int spaceCount = 0;
        for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == ' ') {
                spaceCount++;
            }
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(string);
        Random random = new Random();
        int length = string.length();
        int i = length - (length / maskingRatio) - spaceCount;
        while (i > 0){
            int stringIndex = random.nextInt(length);
            System.out.println(stringIndex);
            if ((builder.charAt(stringIndex) != ' ') && (builder.charAt(stringIndex) != maskingChar.charAt(0))){
                builder.replace(stringIndex, stringIndex + 1, maskingChar);
                i--;
            }
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: A simple approach is to only uncover odd letters.

Comment: But my masking ratio can be 1 to 5, and if I only uncover odd letters it will be 1 to 2.

Comment: I didn’t say uncover *all* odd, just *only* odd

Comment: Q: Out of curiousity, what would the "masking ratio" be for `Michael Jackson` into `*i*h*** *******`?  Also - if you're doing division, why is your arithmetic all in integer space?

Comment: The masking ratio will be 5

Comment: @Bohemian can you please elaborate. I clearly have not understood what you suggested...

Comment: I m not exactly sure how you want it to work. Can you please give more information? For example: Michael Jackson (14 chars, 1 Space, String.length = 15). What shall happen if I have a masking ratio of 2 or 3? What characters shall be masked, when the ratio is clear, shall it be random?

Comment: The masking ratio is at least 50 percent.

Comment: Given a string of length `n`, many letters do you want hidden? Note that the lower limit is `n / 2` if no adjacent letters are to remain visible.

Answer (score 0):

If the masking ratio is less than 50%, then you will face the two consecutive characters problem anyway. If you can guarantee that the masking ratio can be more than 50%, then you can unconditionally mask the odd places, and then randomize the rest until you hit the masking ration you desire.

Answer (score -1):

I will assume that you only want *odd* letters to be removed, and *even* ones left alone. According to the ASCII table. That is how I am interpreting it. So I am excluding the masking ratio since the question is vague.

This the way I would do it,

The Code:

```
 public static String mask(String text, char maskingChar) {
         char ch = ' ';
         String newText = "";

         for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
             ch = text.charAt(i);
             if (ch != ' ') {
                 newText += maskingChar;
             } else {
                 newText += " ";
             }
         }
         return newText;
     }
```

---

Output:

```
******* *******
```

7 letters, plus 1 space and 7 letters = 15 characters, the original input.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, or even addresses removing odd-only letters.

Comment: So did he mean to leave even letters and mask the odd ones according to the ASCII table?